# hot code loading in haskell

Tags: haskell

It is possible to implement hot code swapping with Haskell? I was reading about Erlang which sparked up my interest, I would like to use these features with Haskell.

Comment: https://code.facebook.com/posts/745068642270222/fighting-spam-with-haskell/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the package [dyre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dyre), which was designed for exactly this kind of purpose.  There's also [hotswap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hotswap), but it hasn't been updated for a few years now.

Comment: any experience with it for large web/cloud based projects?

Comment: @DanielWagner dyre looks more promising

Comment: btw, it seems like dyre calls GHC by subprocess, rather than using the GHC API.

Answer (score 10):

There is `plugins` package in Cabal, which provides facilities for loading plugins code. But in general Haskell is much more hostile to changing code in runtime than dynamic, bytecode-driven Erlang.